Complexity of FirstMatch (Prefix Elimination) Operator for regular expressions
Consider the operator $\texttt{FirstMatch} : 2^{\Sigma^*} \to 2^{\Sigma^*}$ defined as follows:
$$\texttt{FirstMatch}(L) = \left \{ y \mid y \in L, \forall \text{ prefixes } x \text{ of } y, x \not \in L \right \}$$
What is the complexity of matching regular expressions with this operator? (i.e, regular expressions with union, concatenation, Kleene iteration and FirstMatch)
Does this operator make regular expressions more succinct? Can the FirstMatch operator be applied on NFAs (without determinization)?
